# How can I insert session data into a database?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have set up a shopping basket which is a  session list is stored in a session array called `['list']`. I want to extract the session data (information about list items) and insert them into a database table.

```
session_start();
Print_r ($_SESSION['list']);

if ( !isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['list']) )
{
   header("Location:index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Result:

Array ( [1] => Array ( [ISBN] => 0923184232 [bookname] => asodiaso [author] => lolstan [price] => 5.99 ) [2] => Array ( [ISBN] => 6677889900 [bookname] => The Templars Code [author] => C.M. Palov [price] => 18.99 ) )

^ I want this information inserted into a table! :)

By using this I can print off the session variables contained within the Array but what I need to do is to extract the variables and then insert them into another database table. 
 I have no idea how to go about extracting them so any suggestions?

I am familiar with how to insert information into the database tables (MYSQL).

The insert method looks like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orderhistory VALUES ('','".$ISBN."','".$bookname."','".$author."','".$price."', '')";
```

At the moment my addtobasket.php looks like:

`

```
require "dbconn.php";

//Connects to database
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password )
or die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");

//Make sure we are using the right database
mysql_select_db($database);

$ISBN = $_SESSION['list']['ISBN'];
$bookname = $_SESSION['list']['bookname'];
$author = $_SESSION['list']['author'];
$price = $_SESSION['list']['price'];

// Set up the query using the values that were passed via the URL from the form
$query = "INSERT INTO orderhistory 
VALUES('','".$ISBN."','".$bookname."','".$author."','".$price."', '')";
```

Yes, I know it is wrong! :((

Comment: What problems are you having?  What have you attempted in terms of extraction and database insertion?

Comment: If you're given an array of data can you insert it to a database (What I mean is are you familiar with how to insert into db ?) Can you post how your session variable looks.

Comment: In the session lit contains are you storing the information about item

Comment: Sorry for the vague information ill edit it now

Comment: What do you mean by extracting?  Maybe you're looking for a foreach loop???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to dump the contents of your variable in a database field, you can use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert your array to a string that you can easily convert back.

By the way, I would strongly suggest switching to PDO and prepared statements to avoid the basic sql injection problems.

Comment: Though technically correct, storing data in a manner like that in a *relational* database is typically a horrible idea.

Comment: @Corbin I agree, but the alternative would be a shopping-cart table for unprocessed orders and that approach - although better - would take more time as I assume that the reading and writing of the cart is already in place for the session variables. But you are right.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use serialize() or json_encode() I've never used that before.. sorry! :(

Comment: @silverj2k7 Using `$list_string = serialize($_SESSION['list']);` you get a variable that is a string. That string you can save in a `text` or `varchar` (etc...) field like any other string.

Comment: Hmm when I echo that it gives me all sorts of information:

a:2:{i:1;a:4:{s:4:"ISBN";s:10:"0923184232";s:8:"bookname";s:8:"asodiaso";s:6:"author";s:7:"lolstan";s:5:"price";s:4:"5.99";}i:2;a:4:{s:4:"ISBN";s:10:"6677889900";s:8:"bookname";s:17:"The Templars Code";s:6:"author";s:10:"C.M. Palov";s:5:"price";s:5:"18.99";}}

Comment: @silverj2k7 The important thing is that it is a string you can store. To recreate your array you just do: `$_SESSION['list'] = unserialize($list_string);`

Comment: Hmm okay, I understand but How would I go about storing these strings now? as there will be multiple items :)

Comment: @silverj2k7 You are missing the point, *the whole array* is stored in that one string.

Comment: Erm okay, I think I am missing the point. Because if it is stored as a single string how would I go about spilting it up and inserting it? =///

Comment: Then perhaps you should, in your PHP function, store each dimension of the `$_SESSION` array into seperate variables, then use those broken down variables to use as the variable for MySQL data insertion.  Example: `$author = $_SESSION['list']['author']` then use the `$author` variable, after properly sanitizing, into your DB

Comment: @silverj2k7 My original suggestion was not to split anything but dump the whole shopping cart in one database field. If that is not what you want, you need to show us the structure of your database table where you want to store the cart items.

Comment: @jeroen Very true.  I suppose as long as the operations performed on the cart remain simple, it should not matter.  Might should avoid teaching noobies bad habits though.  (Though as you said, doing it the other way would take more time, and would be a much longer answer [out of the scope of SO style answer].)

Comment: Okay - The structure of the database table looks like this:
http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c349/jb_dude/orderhistory.png

Comment: The reason I find this so confusing is it works like this: 
User adds book to shopping basket (Addtolist.php)

Which the list is set up as an array:

 $bookarray = array();
 $bookarray['ISBN'] = $_GET['ISBN'];
 $bookarray['bookname'] = $_GET['bookname'];
 $bookarray['author'] = $_GET['author'];
 $bookarray['price'] = $_GET['price'];
Then I need to extract and store the array variables in the orderhistory table using the addtobasket.php file. I suck at explaining stuff so sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: @silverj2k7 shopping cart != order history.

Comment: yeah I will think rename order history to just order.

Comment: Okay orderhistory is now order, what to do next is get those variables into the table fields!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this kind of code will help you:

```
$con = mysql_connect('myserver', 'myusername', 'mypassword') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);

$insert_query = "UPDATE mytable SET field='" . $_SESSION["value"] . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'";

$result = mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: That's open to SQL injection.

Comment: I agree but that is not the point :-)

Comment: Security is not an issue at the moment. I am just trying to get the basic function working. :)

Comment: Update: Changed $_REQUEST[] with $_SESSION[]

Comment: Security is not the only concern.  What if one of the fields has a legitimate ' in it?  Escaping strings in SQL is just as much about correctness as security.  It's the same idea as trying to write $a = '''; in PHP (a single quote inside of two single quotes).  It's just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orderhistory
VALUES('','".$ISBN."','".$bookname."','".$author."','".$price."', '')";
```

needs to be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orderhistory
VALUES('', '$ISBN', '$bookname', '$author', '$price')"
```

You have way too many, and unnecessary quotes

You don't need the final `''` in the field, as long as you have it set as NULL in the DB (which you don't).  If you are expecting to use a blank field in `date` with every insertion, I would suggest making that `NULL` in the db

Comment: I made the final field (date) Null now and have updated it, thanks.